# Parsing multiple "msg" files and storing the body text in a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, msg

a python Newbie here. I am currently trying to figure out how to parse all the msg files I have stored in a specific folder and then save the body text to a csv file.

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(r"C:\Users\XY\Documents\Email Reader\test.msg")


print(msg.Body)

del outlook, msg
```

So far, I only found a way to open one specific msg file, but not all the files I stored in my folder. I think I should be able to handle storing the data in a csv file, but I just can't figure out how to read multiple msg files. Hope you can help me!

cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this to iterate through every file with '.msg' extension in a directory:

```
import os

pathname = os.fsencode('Pathname as string')

for file in os.listdir(pathname):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".msg"):
        #Do something
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I keep getting two different error messages, depending on the approach I take. 

If I use: "os.fsencode('C:\Users\XY\Documents\Email Reader')", it spits out this syntaxxerror: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: If I do it like this: pathname = os.fsencode('Users\XY\Documents\Email Reader'),

I get a file not found error stopping at the for loop in line 5

Comment: The '\' is an escape character. You should use either 
`os.fsencode('C:/Users/XY/Documents/Email Reader')`
or
`os.fsencode('C:\\Users\\XY\\Documents\\Email Reader')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pathlib` to iterate over the contents of the directory.
Try this:

```
from pathlib import Path
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

# Assuming \Documents\Email Reader is the directory containg files
for p in Path(r'C:\Users\XY\Documents\Email Reader').iterdir():
    if p.is_file() and p.suffix == '.msg':
        msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(p)
        print(msg.Body)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I keep getting a TypeError in line 7 at the beginning of the for loop. It says ' WindowsPath object is ont iterable'.

thanks!

Comment: @Tom Apologies. I for loop is supposed to call `iterdir`. I have ammended the code sample.

Comment: thanks, it works perfectly fine now. I really appreciate you guys taking the time! :)